# Использование циклов для рендера компонентов React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты! Я хочу сделать таблицу 10x10 из одинаковых элементов в React, но копипастить каждый компонент 10 раз это неудобно и делает код громоздким, можно ли как-то организовать их рендер более удобным способом? Как использовать циклы в React?

Answer (score 1):

По сути, в реакте циклов нет, реакт сам перебирает массивы, надо лишь что бы каждый элемент массива был в нужном формате, по этому для данной задачи решение будет что-то в духе:

```
const Table = () => (
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {Array(10).map((row, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          {Array(10).map((cell, i) => <td key={i}>&nbsp;</td>)}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```